# How to show a map: $\varphi: GL_n( \Bbb Z_p ) \to \Phi(p)$ where p is prime is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

$\varphi: GL_n( \Bbb Z_p ) \to \Phi(p); \varphi GL_n( \Bbb Z_p ) $ is the general linear Gropu with entries in $\Bbb Z_p$
$\Phi(p)=$ the set of invertable elements of $\Bbb Z_p$
$\varphi(GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)) = [det( GL_n(\Bbb Z_p))]_p $
or simply what does a matrix look like such that its determinant is $ x \in \Phi(p)$?

Comment: Try a diagonal matrix.  You don't want the determinant to be $p$, you want it to be an arbitrary invertible residue class in $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

Comment: Just to repeat and emphasize @Slade's comment: $p$ is not invertible in $\mathbb Z_p$, although it is in $\mathbb Q_p$, in the same way that a prime $p$ is not invertible in $\mathbb Z$, but is in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: thanks, i fixed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am reading your question wrong, let $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$.  Then the matrix with $a$ in the upper left hand corner, $1$'s down the rest of the diagonal, and $0$'s everywhere else will have determinant $a$.

Comment: yeah that's it, thanks.